# Using C#, webdriver with Xunit , is any listener present in Xunit , which will listen number of test cases passed or failed , like IReporter in TestNG

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Using C#, webdriver with Xunit , is any listener present in Xunit , which will listen number of test cases passed or failed , like IReporter in TestNG

Comment: What do you mean 'listen'? This doesn't make much sense. How are you running the tests? Does your test runner not show what tests have passed?

Comment: sorry for confusion , need to update the question, will do that